# Did Canvas or drawBitmap change in ICS?

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I'm making updates to a live wallpaper I've developed. The wallpaper is currently running correctly on a 2.2 device, but NOT on my 4.2 device.

On the ICS device, it seems that only the last column is being correctly drawn. For example, in a coordinate system, if my phone is 420 x 720 (not sure of the exact dimensions), then only pixels (420, 0) through (420, 720) are being drawn. The rest is black / transparent.

Here's the code I'm using: https://github.com/gjtorikian/Earthbound-Battle-Backgrounds/blob/master/src/com/miadzin/livewallpaper/earthbound/EarthboundLiveWallpaper.java#L243

First, I draw a 256 x 256 bitmap. Then, I use a matrix to scale it.

Again, this works fine on a non-ICS device. Another tricky aspect is that I'm using the JNI to do some of the bitmap math, but I still think the problem is in this canvas code somewhere.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, so after days I finally figured it out.

After creating my bitmap, I need to set every pixel in Java:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 254; x++) {
    for (int y =0; y < 254; y++) {
      bmp.setPixel(x, y, Color.argb(255, 0, 0, 0));
    }
}
```

The question is: WHY only for ICS?